# Problem at getting+tweeting latest tweet from a user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm a newbie at this and I'm trying to get the latest tweet from someone (in this case @Twitter) and automatically tweet the same thing.
After looking at different people's code, I came up with this:

```
def user_tweet(twitter):
    statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter)
    return statuses[0].text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    latest_tweet = user_tweet(sys.argv[1])
    api.update_status(latest_tweet)
```

however I have a few questions,

- I need to type "python name_file.py twitter" for it to work, how do I make it work by just executing it ("python name_file.py")? So without any input.
- I want it to include different twitter profiles to randomly choose from after 30 mins each time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- to execute it directly using script you need to define `username` (`twitter`) argument in script.
  Example:

```
my_twitter_id = 'abcd'
def user_tweet(twitter):
    statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter)
    return statuses[0].text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    latest_tweet = user_tweet(my_twitter_id )
    api.update_status(latest_tweet)
```

- For your second part use python `random.choice` to select one randomly every 30 minute.